# Why does R change the variable type when prepending NA values to a data frame with factors?

Tags: r, dataframe, na, rbind, r-factor

I have a problem with the way R coerces variable types when using `rbind` of two `data.frames` with `NA` values. I illustrate by example:

```
x<-factor(sample(1:3,10,T))
y<-rnorm(10)
dat<-data.frame(x,y)
NAs<-data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=ncol(dat),nrow=nrow(dat)))
colnames(NAs)<-colnames(dat)
```

Now the goal is to append `dat` and `NAs` while keeping the variable types `factor` and `numeric` of `x` and `y`. When I give:

```
dat_forward<-rbind(dat,NAs)
is.factor(dat_forward$x)
```

this works fine. However the backward direction using `rbind` fails:

```
dat_backward<-rbind(NAs,dat)
is.factor(dat_backward$x)
is.character(dat_backward$x)
```

Now `x` is coerced to character level. I am confused - can't it stay factor type even if I use the other order of binding? What would be a straight forward change to my code to reach my goal?

Comment: From `?rbind.data.frame`: "It then takes the classes of the columns from the first data frame...". This is why you're seeing the order matter in your call to `rbind`.

Comment: @josilber Thank you, is there a straight forward fix to my problem?

Comment: convert the first column of `NAs` to factor?

Comment: @josilber `rbind(dat[0,], NAs, dat)` seems to contradict that.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde One sentence earlier in the documentation: "The rbind data frame method first drops all zero-column and zero-row arguments."

Comment: Thanks for all replies above and below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a fairly simple way to get the column classes right:

```
x <- rbind(dat[1,], NAs, dat)[-1,]
str(x)
#  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ y: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

---

More generally, if you are *really* needing this often, you could create an `rbind`-like function that takes an additional argument indicating the data.frame to whose column classes you'd like to coerce all of the others' columns:

```
myrbind <- function(x, ..., template=x) {
    do.call(rbind, c(list(template[1,]), list(x), list(...)))[-1,]
}

str(myrbind(NAs, dat,  template=dat))
# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ y: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

## If no 'template' argument is supplied, myrbind acts just like rbind    
str(myrbind(dat, NAs))
# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 3 2 ...
#  $ y: num  0.303 1.77 -1.38 1.731 0.033 ...
```

Comment: Thanks, both an easy solution and a nice function.

Answer (score 3):

Similarly, you could just convert the column in `NAs` to `factor`

```
NAs$x<-factor(NAs$x)
dat_backward<-rbind(NAs,dat) 
is.factor(dat_backward$x) # TRUE
is.character(dat_backward$x) # FALSE
```

Answer (score 3):

`data.frame` does a lot of things incorrectly when `rbind`'ing different types together, and especially when that involves factors. Start using `data.table` (1.8.11+) instead and you won't have these issues:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(dat)
dt2 = data.table(NAs)

sapply(rbind(dt1, dt2), class)
#        x         y 
# "factor" "numeric" 
sapply(rbind(dt2, dt1), class)
#        x         y 
# "factor" "numeric"
```

Answer (score 2):

From `?rbind.data.frame`, we read: "It then takes the classes of the columns from the first data frame...". This is why you're seeing the order matter in your call to `rbind`.

To get the variable classes of `dat_forward` with the ordering of `dat_backward`, you could just construct `dat_forward` and reorder the rows:

```
dat_new = rbind(dat, NAs)[c((nrow(dat)+1):(nrow(dat)+nrow(NAs)), 1:nrow(dat)),]
str(dat_new)
# 'data.frame': 20 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
#  $ y: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create `NAs` with the correct column datatypes. This can be easily done with

```
NAs <- dat[NA,]
```

You can also make as many rows as desired with

```
num.rows <- 30
NAs <- dat[NA,][1:num.rows,]
```